# parameter evaluation of function call from a macro

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I have a function and one macro in which the function is called.
And to see the difference, I trace the function and found that there was no difference whether it is called directly or from the macro.
I wonder why the parameter was not evaluated when called from macro.
I know that parameters passed to a macro will not be evaluated but even this happens to the parameters passed to a function from a macro?
To be specific, I mean why **(< 7 5)** is not evaluated to **nil** when passed to **gen-lisp**

The function:

```
(defun gen-lisp (expr binds)
  expr)
```

The macro:

```
(defmacro dsptch-prove-query (query binds)
  `(if (eq (car ',query) 'lisp)
       ,(gen-lisp (cadr query) binds)
     (prove-query ',query ,binds)))
```

Result when called from macro:

```
 (dsptch-prove-query (lisp (< 7 5)) nil)
1. Trace: (GEN-LISP '(< 7 5) 'NIL)
1. Trace: GEN-LISP ==> (< 7 5)
NIL
```

Result when called directly:

```
 (gen-lisp '(< 7 5) 'NIL)
1. Trace: (GEN-LISP '(< 7 5) 'NIL)
1. Trace: GEN-LISP ==> (< 7 5)
(< 7 5)
```

And if I just do it like this below, it is evaluated to **nil** already.

```
(gen-lisp (< 7 5) nil)
1. Trace: (GEN-LISP 'NIL 'NIL)
1. Trace: GEN-LISP ==> NIL
NIL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your macro calls the function `gen-lisp` at macro-expansion time in order to compute a part of the macro-expansion.

The expression which calls the function is this:

```
(gen-lisp (cadr query) binds)
```

this is a function call, which specifies two argument expressions: `(cadr query)` and `binds`.   These expressions **most certainly are** evaluated  as forms and their resulting values constitute the arguments which the function receives.

The macro's `query` parameter's argument value is the nested list object `(lisp (< 7 5))` and so `(cadr query)` calculates the object `(< 7 5)`.  Of course this *itself* isn't evaluated as a form. Evaluation is done, and `(< 7 5)` is its result, which gets passed into the function as its leftmost argument.

What's going on inside the macro is very similar to this:

```
(let ((query '(lisp (< 7 5)))  ;; analogous to macro's query param
      (binds nil))
  (gen-lisp (cadr query) binds)) ;; of course (< 7 5) not evaled
```

If `(< 7 5)` were reduced to `nil`, that would be a *double evaluation*. Nothing in the code calls for a double evaluation. (For instance, we do not see any direct or indirect use of the `eval` function which could request that extra evaluation).

Comment: I supposed the evaluation of a parameter in a function is recursive. It is strange that it is only evaluated once from my point of view.

Answer (score 4):

Your macro is:

```
(defmacro dsptch-prove-query (query binds)
  `(if (eq (car ',query) 'lisp)
       ,(gen-lisp (cadr query) binds)
     (prove-query ',query ,binds)))
```

The macro calls the function `gen-lisp`. The arguments are computed by `(cadr query)` and `binds`. `query` is a list. `(cadr query)` computes the second element of that list. That's the evaluation going on. There is no reason why it should evaluate the result of `(cadr query)`.

**Remember: macros are getting source code passed. They compute with code.**

Just passing the code around does not evaluate the code.

Answer (score 1):

`gen-lisp` returns whatever argument it receives.
As a function, it does not evaluate its arguments.
If you want the argument to be evaluated, you should turn it into a macro (which you would probably want to do anyway when you start to use the `binds` argument in non-trivial way)